# Datavisualization with Tikz: how to customize the formatting of values in the axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Here's a screenshot of the pgf-tikz manual (section 82.2.5, page 878 on manual version 3.1.8b):
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
    \tikz \datavisualization [scientific axes,
x axis={logarithmic}, y axis={logarithmic}, visualize as line]
data [format=function] {
var x : interval [0.01:100]; func y = \value x * \value x;
};
\end{document}
```

How to customize the values displayed for a more harmonised result?
For example, on the y-axis, we see:

- scientific notation (eg: 1·10^{-2});
- decimal value (eg: 0.1);
- integer value (eg: 100).

This seems not acceptable in scientific plotting.

Is there a way to change this?

I'm aware of section **82.4.11 Styling Ticks and Grid Lines: Styling and Typesetting a Value**, but, this is a manual solution for each value in the y-axis (or x-axis).

If there is a solution for display all value in scientific notation, I hope I can drop the unnecessary "1·" before the power of 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section of the manual you point to actually gives the general answer, at the very end: `tick typesetter`.

The example in the manual defines a macro for the number formatting, but you can use `\pgfmathprintnumber` directly, as in the example below. See chapter 97 *Number printing* in the manual for all the options related to formatting of numbers with `\pgfmathprintnumber`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz \datavisualization [
  scientific axes,
  x axis={logarithmic},
  y axis={logarithmic,
          ticks={
             tick typesetter/.code={%
                  \pgfmathprintnumber[sci, retain unit mantissa=false]{##1}
                   }
                }
          },
  visualize as line
  ]
data [format=function] {
var x : interval [0.01:100]; func y = \value x * \value x;
};
\end{document}
```